# How can I store a sbyte value in a byte variable?

Tags: c#, byte, unsigned

I am programming in C#.
I have a sbyte variable.
Say it holds -10 which in binary is 11110110.
I want to store the binary representation of this value in a byte variable.
So when I copy the sbyte (-10) to the byte the bytes value would be 245.
If I try to use Convert.ToByte(sbyte) it throws an exception which makes sense. 
I really don't want to convert from one type to the other but rather make bit-wise copy.
How can I do that?

Comment: Curiousity drives me to ask, Why is the variable an sbyte ?  What does it hold ?

Comment: Well the value is getting sent across a the USB bus to a device. The tool I am using to send data only takes byte arrays. The device firmware will know to interpret this particular byte as a signed byte on the other side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just cast:

```
byte b = (byte) x;
```

If your code is normally running in a checked context, you'll want to make this operation unchecked:

```
byte b = unchecked((byte) x);
```

Note that -10 will become 246, not 245.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it:

```
byte b = 130;
sbyte a = (sbyte)b;
byte c = (byte)a; // will still be 130
```